# Accessing Apollo mutations from express using apollo-server-express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, apollo

I'm using apollo server express. I need to be able to, when using the express part, make a mutation to update some user data on the apollo side. Does anyone know how to be able to make this?

Comment: Accessing apollo mutation from where?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I'm using apollo-express . I need to access the apollo mutations from the express part of the server